# Conversion error when adding additional clauses

Tags: error-handling, data-conversion, winsql

need your expertise on the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". Much written about it and tried looking though it and understanding it to the extend I could but it did not solve the issue.

My code includes a number on conversations from dates and strings to the common numerical format. The conversation work separately form the main code and even together when the code is loose. However, when I start adding more conditions in the "where" function, SQL doesn't seem to like it. Do you possible know how to handle it best? Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT              
 
                    
DOTWHL as "DC",
DORELD as "Release date", 
DODLDT as "Prelim ETA", 
DOITNO as "Item #",
MMITDS as "Item name",
MMSTCN as "Lkr",
DOPPQT as "Plan Qty",
DOPPQT/MMCFI2 as "Plan Qty, pall",
DOPSTS as "Sts",
SUM(MHFOQT) as "FC between ETA & BBD",
MLSTQT as "Stock, LHU",
MMCFI2 as "LHU/PAL",
MMCFI3 as "LHU/Layer",

CASE WHEN DOPPQT >= MLSTQT
     THEN CASE  
                WHEN MLSTQT > SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN 'YES'
                ELSE 'NO'
                END
     ELSE CASE
                WHEN DOPPQT > SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN 'YES'
                ELSE 'NO'
                END
     END AS "FEFO violation necessary?", 

CASE WHEN DOPPQT >= MLSTQT
     THEN CASE  
                WHEN MLSTQT > SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN SUM(MHFOQT)
                ELSE MLSTQT
                END
     ELSE CASE
                WHEN DOPPQT > SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN SUM(MHFOQT)
                ELSE DOPPQT
                END
     END AS "Recommended Qty, LHU",    

CASE WHEN DOPPQT >= MLSTQT
     THEN CASE  
                WHEN MLSTQT > SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN SUM(MHFOQT)/MMCFI2
                ELSE MLSTQT/MMCFI2
                END
     ELSE CASE
                WHEN DOPPQT > SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN SUM(MHFOQT)/MMCFI2
                ELSE DOPPQT/MMCFI2
                END
     END AS "Recommended Qty, pall",  

MLBREF as "Batch",

CASE WHEN MLSTQT > DOPPQT
     THEN CASE  
                WHEN DOPPQT < SUM(MHFOQT)
                THEN SUM(MHFOQT)-DOPPQT
                ELSE NULL
                END
     ELSE NULL
     END AS "Fill Up possibility, LHU",

Sales.Sold_Qty as "Sold Qty 10 weeks",
Sales.Forecasted_Qty as "FC Qty 10 weeks",
ISNULL(Sales.Sold_Qty/NULLIF(Sales.Forecasted_Qty,0), 0) as "Sold/FC, %",
MBBUYE as "NP",
MMRESP as "DmP",
CASE
    WHEN Other_Assortments.item <> 0 THEN 'Many Markets'
    ELSE 'DC 091 only'
    END as "Distributed on"
    
FROM MVXJDTA.MDOPLP 

LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITMAS
    ON DOCONO=MMCONO AND DOITNO=MMITNO
    
LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITBAL
    ON DOCONO=MBCONO AND DOFWHL=MBWHLO AND DOITNO=MBITNO

LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITSTA
    ON DOCONO=MHCONO AND DOTWHL=MHWHLO AND DOITNO=MHITNO
    
LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITLOC
    ON DOCONO=MLCONO AND DOFWHL=MLWHLO AND DOITNO=MLITNO

LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
        MHITNO as "Item_#",
        sum(MHSOQT) as "Sold_Qty",
        sum(MHFOQT) as "Forecasted_Qty"
        FROM MVXJDTA.MITSTA
        WHERE MHCONO=1
        AND MHWHLO='091'
        AND MHCYP6 between 
        (cast(datepart(yyyy, dateadd(ww,-10,getdate())) as varchar) + right('00' + cast(datepart(ww, dateadd(ww,-10,getdate())) as varchar),2)) and
        (cast(datepart(yyyy, dateadd(ww,-1,getdate())) as varchar) + right('00' + cast(datepart(ww, dateadd(ww,-1,getdate())) as varchar),2))
        AND right(MHCYP6, 2) <>'00'
        group by MHITNO
        ) 
        as Sales
        on DOITNO=Sales.Item_#

LEFT JOIN
    (
        select distinct
        OIITNO as "item"
        from MVXJDTA.OCUSMA
        left join MVXJDTA.OASCUS
        on OKCONO=OCCONO and OKCUNO=OCCUNO
        left join MVXJDTA.OASITN
        on OKCONO=OICONO and OCASCD=OIASCD
        where OKCONO=1
        and OITDAT='99999999'
        and OKCSCD<>'KR'
        and OKCSCD<>'HK'
        and OKCSCD<>'TW'
        and OKCSCD<>'SG'
        and OKCSCD<>'MY'
        and OKCSCD<>'TH'
        and OKCSCD<>'PH'
        group by OIITNO) as Other_Assortments
        on Other_Assortments.item=DOITNO

WHERE DOCONO=1
AND DOTWHL='091'
AND DOFWHL='010'
AND MHCYP6 NOT IN (
                    SELECT 
                    MHCYP6 
                    FROM MVXJDTA.MITSTA 
                    WHERE MHWHLO='091'
                    AND MHCONO=1 
                    AND RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, MHCYP6, 102), 2) ='00'
                    )
AND MHCYP6 BETWEEN  
                    
                    CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(DODLDT, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(DODLDT, 4), 2) + '/' + LEFT (DODLDT, 4), 103))<10
                    THEN    CONCAT(    DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(DODLDT, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(DODLDT, 4), 2) + '/' + LEFT (DODLDT, 4), 103)), 0,
                            DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(DODLDT, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(DODLDT, 4), 2) + '/' + LEFT (DODLDT, 4), 103)))
                    ELSE    CONCAT(    DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(DODLDT, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(DODLDT, 4), 2) + '/' + LEFT (DODLDT, 4), 103)),
                            DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(DODLDT, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(DODLDT, 4), 2) + '/' + LEFT (DODLDT, 4), 103)))
                    END
                    
                                       
                    CASE 
                    WHEN MLBREF IS NULL 
                    THEN '999999' 
                    ELSE CASE 
                        WHEN    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -82, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(MLBREF, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(MLBREF, 4), 2) + '/' + '20'+LEFT (MLBREF, 2), 103)))<10 
                        THEN    CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -82, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(MLBREF, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(MLBREF, 4), 2) + '/' + '20'+LEFT (MLBREF, 2), 103))), 0,
                                DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -82, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(MLBREF, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(MLBREF, 4), 2) + '/' + '20'+LEFT (MLBREF, 2), 103))))
                        ELSE    CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, -82, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(MLBREF, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(MLBREF, 4), 2) + '/' + '20'+LEFT (MLBREF, 2), 103))),
                                DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -82, CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(MLBREF, 2) + '/' + LEFT(RIGHT(MLBREF, 4), 2) + '/' + '20'+LEFT (MLBREF, 2), 103))))
                        END
                    END
                
AND (MLSTQT-MLALQT)<>0
GROUP BY DOTWHL, DORELD, MLBREF, DODLDT, DOITNO, DOPPQT, MLSTQT, MMITDS, MLALQT, MBPLCD, MMSTCN, MMCFI2, MMCFI3, DOPSTS, Sales.Sold_Qty, Sales.Forecasted_Qty, MBBUYE, MMRESP, Other_Assortments.item
ORDER BY DOTWHL, DORELD
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't mysql code - is the question about t-sql/sql-server/mssql?

Comment: thanks! corrected to WinSQL